# How do I stream Stereo Mix Audio?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone, audio-recording

I have seen many people asking how to record Stereo Mix alongside microphone using programs like audacity, but is there a way to stream it somewhere? I.E. Omegle or Chatroulette? Long story short, when I'm bored I pass the time by playing music or video clips for people via Omegle (sad, I know) but if there's any way to do it I'd love to hear it. Thanks!

Comment: Note: I do not want to record audio, I want to use my stereo mix as I would a microphone like I would in Windows.

Comment: Please [edit] your question, when you want to add information. It's best to have everything relevant in one place. Also, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Answer (score -2):

Fixed via pavucontrol and pavm

Comment: Could you elaborate on both the question ans answer, please?